# Get bits from a binary

Tags: elixir

I'm writing a bitstream to base64 encoder for the heck of it and can't seem to find a way to access the raw bits.

Say I've got the bitstring:

```
0100 1101 0110 0001 0110 1110
```

Represented in elixir as:

```
<<77, 97, 110>> # or the string "Man"
```

I need to access the bitstring in chunks of 6 bits in order to encode it as base64. How might one do that? I don't have a lot of experience working with raw binary so I might be going about this naively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can arbitrarily take individual bit groups from a binary:

```
iex(1)> <<a :: 6, b :: 6, c:: 6, d::6>> = <<77, 97, 110>>

iex(2)> [a,b,c,d]
[19, 22, 5, 46]
```

Or you can use the [for comprehension](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1):

```
iex(3)> for <<x :: 6 <- <<77, 97, 110>> >>, do: x
[19, 22, 5, 46]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention that your ultimate goal is to encode a bitstring as base64, you can use [the `:base64` module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/base64.html):

```
iex> :base64.encode "Man"
"TWFu"
```